# How to make an image responsive using bootstrap without having it take up the entire width of the division?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone who has used twitter bootstrap knows that an image can be made responsive using the `img-responsive` class in the html img tag. However, these images take up 100% of the width of the division.

How can I make the image responsive while still keeping its original width?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put the image in a wrapper and give the wrapper the width you want the image to have.
**HTML**

```
<div class="imgwrapper">
   <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgwrapper {
   width: 80%;
}
```

The above should in theory make the `imgwrapper` 80% of the width of the parent-element, and the `img-responsive`-class on the image will fill up the whole wrapper.

If this doesn't answer your question, could you explain a bit better what you mean with `keep original width, but make it responsive`? Since making it responsive will resize the image, which means it will not have the original width.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a wrapper around the image defining the actual size of the parent that could be used to place that image. It will be related to the parent div. Then apply .img-responsive to the image. This will cause the image to have the same width as the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="your-image.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
   width: 50%;
}
```

If you want to keep the original size (it will be resized to have small size but never higher), you should also add a `max-width` which will have to correspond to the image's original size. This will overwrite the original value of 100%

```
.wrapper img {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.img-responsive` class applies  `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image, so if you want to keep its original width explicitly you have to set width of image using width attribute of img tag.